# fill dropdown with firestore database error flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

hello there I need to fill my dropdown list from firestore database in flutter and always I got this error

> There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: . Either zero or 2 or more[DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':Failed assertion: line 890 pos 15: 'items ==null|| items.isEmpty || value == null ||items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) {return item.value == value;}).length == 1'

```
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('guests').snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

        currencyItems = [];
        snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
          currencyItems.add(
            DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(
                data["name"]
              ),
              value: data["id"],
            ),
          );
          print(" dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa $data");
        }).toList();

        return DropdownButton(
          items: currencyItems,
          onTap:(){
            print(currencyItems);
          } ,
          onChanged: (currencyValue) {

            final snackBar = SnackBar(
              content: Text(
                'Selected Currency value is $currencyValue',
                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff11b719)),
              ),
            );
            //Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
            setState(() {
              _value = currencyValue;
            });
          },
          value: _value,
          isExpanded: false,
          hint:  Text(
            "Choose Currency Type",
            style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff11b719)),
          ),
        );

    },
),
```

Comment: Share the data printed  `print(" dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa $data");`

Comment: I/flutter ( 8044):  dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa {email: mehdi@gmail.com, name: mohamed123, id: 178}
I/flutter ( 8044):  dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa {email: khaliltayarth@gmail.com, name: khalil tayarth, id: 383}
I/flutter ( 8044):  dataaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa {name: application test, email: testapp@gmail.com, id: 472}

Comment: Got answer....?

Comment: yes this is my data but it shows me this error( There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value... )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because each `DropDownMenuItem` must have a unique value, but there is multiple with the same value.

Check the data retrieved from firestore.

> Try using `forEach` instead of `map`